# The complexity of the reachability-coreachability analysis of a finite state machine

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata, graph-traversal

Let $A = \{\Sigma,Q,\delta,q_{0}, Q_{m}\}$ be a finite state machine (FSM). A state $q \in Q$ is reachable if there exists a string $s \in \Sigma^{*}$ such that $\delta(q_{0},s) = q$. The state $q$ is coreachable if there exists a string $s$ such that $\delta(q,s) \in Q_{m}$.

I'm wondering what is the computational complexity of the reachability-coreachability analysis of a FSM, as a function of $|Q|=n$.  In particular, the input is a FSM $A$, and I'd like the algorithm to output a list of all states that are reachable, and a list of all states that are coreachable.  What is the worst-case asymptotic complexity of this function, as a function of $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the nature of the OP's question relates to discrete-event systems (as he/she indicated in one of the comments), the argument to derive the complexity can be different compared to what [Apass.Jack](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/91753/apass-jack) proposed, as follows.

Given $n = |Q|$, $m = |Q_{m}|$, and $k = |\delta|$,

Reachability test shall be applied to every state in $Q\setminus\{Q_{m}\dot{\cup}\{q_{0}\}\}$ since the initial state does not need to be reachable, and the reachability of marked states are taken into account by coreachability. So, one has to check the reachability of $n-m-1$ states. Furthermore, coreachability test is only meaningful to $Q_{m}$, and we have to examine it $m$ times. In the worst case, one has to traverse the whole DFA to check (co)reacahbility. Thus, according to the complexity of BFS/DFS, which is, $O(|Q|+|\delta|) = O(n+k)$, one reads

$O((n+k)(n-m-1)) + O((n+k)m) = O((n+k)(n-1)) = O(n^2 + kn -n -k)$.

$n$ and $k$ are negligible since they are much less than $n^2$ and $kn$ yielding

$O(n^2+kn)$

Comment: This shows that there exists an algorithm whose running time is $O(n^2+kn)$, but not that this is the best possible running time (i.e., it doesn't rule out the possibility of some other, faster algorithm).

Comment: @D.W.: (Regarding your comments) do you mean that it is possible to check both the reachbility and the correachability of `all nodes` using only a single DFS? If so, please share it as an answer, and then I'd delete mine which would be reasonably not the best approach anymore.

Comment: @D.W.: I believe that you mean there exists an algorithm with $O(n+k)$. If I got it right, can you elaborate a little bit on the sketch of its proof?

Comment: Nope, that's not what I'm saying.  It's possible to find all reachable nodes in $O(nk)$ time using a single DFS (use do a DFS starting from the initial start state).  That's faster than $O(n^2+kn)$ (if $k$ is smaller than $n$).  Also, it's possible to find all coreachable nodes in $O(nk)$ time as well using a single DFS (create a new state $q_f$; add edges from each state in $Q_m$ to $q_f$; now do a DFS backwards starting from $q_f$).  This is already described in Apass.Jack's answer, so I'm not writing a new answer as that would just duplicate what Apass.Jack has already explained.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m\ge1$ be the size of the alphabet $\Sigma$.

---

Let us restrict our attention to the two most common models of finite state machines (FSM), deterministic finite automatons (DFA) and non-deterministic finite automatons (NFA). We know that FSM corresponds naturally to the directed multi-graph as explained by [Wikipedia entry on state diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram#Directed_graph).

A $n$-state $DFA$ $D=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ corresponds a directed multi-graph $G$, whose nodes are also $Q$ and all of whose nodes have outdegree $m$. Whenever we mention some $q\in Q$, it will be clear whether we mean the state $q$ in $D$ or the node $q$ in $G$. It takes $O(mn)$ time to convert $D$ to $G$.

- The problem of determining all reachable states from state $q_0$ in $D$ corresponds to the problem of determining all reachable nodes from node $q_0$ in $G$. If we use the classic breadth first traversal starting from node $q_0$ to solve the later problem, the worst case happens when we have to go through all arcs in $G$, which is $\Theta(mn)$ time-complexity.  In fact, for any algorithm to determine the set of all reachable nodes, all edges must be checked.
- The problem of determining all co-reachable states in $D$ corresponds to the problem of determining all reachable nodes from $q'$ in graph $G'$, where $G'$ is $G$ with all edges reversed and with one extra node $q'$ that is connected to all node $q_i\in F$. The conversion from $G$ to $G'$ takes $O(mn+n) = O(mn)$ time. If we use the classic breadth first traversal starting from node $q'$ to solve the later problem of all reachable nodes, the worst case happens when we have to go through all arcs in $G'$, which is $\Theta(m(n+1)=\Theta(mn)$ time-complexity. In fact, it is easy to see that asymptotically, solving the problem of co-reachability has the same worst-case time-complexity as solving the problem of reachability.

To summarize, the worse case to determine the reachability or co-reachability of a $n$-state DFA takes $\Theta(mn)$ time.

---

In this section, we will explain the exact meaning of the statement "all edges must be checked" for the case of reachable states.

(**All edges by adversary**) Let $G$ be a multi-graph $G$ of $n$ nodes and a start node $q_0$. Each node $q$ has exactly $m$ outgoing edges $\{q_\sigma\mid \sigma\in\Sigma \}$. The only way for us to know the other endpoint of $q_\sigma$ is to inquire from a truthful smart adversary $A$, who can config the other endpoint on the fly. Each inquiry must be "which node is the endpoint of $q_\sigma$ other than $q$?" for some $v$ and $\sigma$. The minimal number of inquiries needed to determine the set of reachable nodes from $q_0$ is $mn$.

Proof. Let $Q=\{q_0, q_1, \cdots, q_{n-1}\}$.

Here is $A$'s strategy to reply to the inquiry. Initialize $n$ empty set $S_q$, $q\in Q$. For an inquiry about $q_\sigma$ with $q=q_i$, there are five cases.

- if $i\lt n-2$ and $\#S_q\lt m-1$, reply that $q_\sigma$ is the loop from $q$ to $q$. Add $\sigma$ to $S_q$.
- if $i\lt n-2$ and $\#S_q= m-1$, reply that $q_\sigma= (q,q_{i+1})$. Add $\sigma$ to $S_q$.
- if $i\ge n-2$ and $\#S_{q_{n-2}} + \#S_{q_{n-1}}\lt 2m-1$, reply that $q_\sigma$ is the loop from $q$ to $q$. Add $\sigma$ to $S_q$.
- if $i\ge n-2$ and $\#S_{q_{n-2}} + \#S_{q_{n-1}}= 2m-1$, reply $q_\sigma=(q_{n-2}, q_{n-1})$ when $q=q_{n-2}$ and reply $q_\sigma=(q_{n-1}, q_0)$ when $q=q_{n-1}$. Add $\sigma$ to $S_q$.
- if $\#S_\sigma= m$, the inquiry must have been done before and, hence, reply the same as before.

I will leave the rest of the proof as an exercise.

---

**Exercise 1**. Finish the proof of "all edges by adversary". Show that $A$'s strategy is consistent in the sense that there is one such $G$ that all replies of $A$ are true. Furthermore, after $mn-1$ inquires, we cannot determine whether $q_{n-1}$ is reachable from $q_0$ or not.

Interested readers can do the following exercise that deals with NFA.

**Exercise 2.** the worse case to determine the reachability or co-reachability of a $n$-state NFA takes $\Theta(mn^2)$ time.

Comment: You might have a different definition of DFA. However, mine is the standard one, as have been confirmed by Raphael, Wikipedia and the book _introduction to the theory of computation_. Anyway, in your definition, the number of edges is not greater than $nm$, correct? It can reach $nm$, right? Then my argument still holds for your version of DFA as well.

Comment: Considering $n$ and $m$ as the state size and the number of transitions, each DFS/BFS requires $O(n+m)$. One needs to check all $n$ states, thereby $O(n^2 + mn)$. Do I miss something?!

Comment: @Roboticist, yes, you are missing something.  Rather than doing $n$ separate DFSs, it is possible to do a *single* DFS.  $m$ is not the number of transitions; $m$ is the out-degree (so the total number of edges is at most $nm$, or is exactly $nm$, depending on which definition of a DFA you use).